# Problemas com criptografia em C++

Tags: c++, criptografia, ascii

Estou fazendo um programa de criptografia que funciona da seguinte forma:
 Ele ira ler uma string e depois somar a cada caractere um numero primo respectivo. 
 Exemplo:

a(+2) b(+3) c(+5) d(+7) e(+11) = c e h k p

Nessa criptografia serão permitidos os caracteres da tabela ASCII de 33 a 125.
 E quando algum numero passasse de 125 voltaria do 33 e continuaria.

Porem não sei como fazer quando é um numero muito grande, por exemplo, se o caractere 'z' estivesse na posição de numero 150 em uma string ele seria somado a  863, ou seja, 122 + 863. Como eu posso fazer para que essa soma se mantenha dentro dos limites de 33 e 125?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::getline;
#include<cstring>
using namespace std; 

int main ()
{
    string crpt_string;

    string std_string;

    int primos[150] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41...809, 
      811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859,
      863};


    cout << "Digte a string a ser criptografada: ";
    getline(cin, crpt_string);

    for ( int a = 0; a <= crpt_string.length(); a++)
    {
        std_string[a] = crpt_string[a] + primos[a];
    }

    printf(std_string.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não cheguei a implementar, mas eu usaria a operação `%` para limitar as entradas, seguindo esses passos:

- converte o caracter para int (ou long, dependendo da necessidade) - isso para pegar o código dele
- subtrai 33
- soma o valor desejado (vamos chamar de `v`)
- faça `v = (v%92)+33` (92 é o número de valores válidos que tu consideras, entre 125 e 33)
- pega o caracter cujo código é `v`

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, fazendo uns testes aqui acho que deu certo. E no caso como seria pra descriptografar? Só faria a operação inversa?

Comment: Não sei dizer se o inverso funcionaria - acredito que sim, mas tem que testar,,,